# convert sql query to Zend DB query

Tags: zend-framework

I have tow table :
article,sub_categories
how to convert this query to zend Db query join

$sql="

SELECT `article`.*, `sub_categories`.`name_arabic` AS `sub_category_name_arabic`, `sub_categories`.`name_english` AS `sub_category_name_english`, `article`.`sub_category_id` AS `sub_categories_id` FROM `article` 
                    LEFT JOIN `sub_categories` ON `article`.`sub_category_id` = `sub_categories`.`id`
                    WHERE `article`.`active` = 1
";

Please need help

Thanks with regard

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$db->select()
   ->from('article', array('*', 'sub_categories_id' => 'sub_category_id')
   ->joinLeft(
        'sub_categories',
        'article.sub_category_id = sub_categories.id',
        array('sub_category_name_arabic' => 'name_arabic', 'sub_category_name_english' => 'name_english'))
   ->where('article.active = 1');
```